# Sorting a hash of hashes in ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

How can I sort this hash of hashes by "clients".  I tried using sort_by, but this transforms it into an array of hashes.  I am using JSON.parse to create this object from a json file.  Thanks!

```
{
  "default_attributes": {
    "clients": {
      "ABC": {
        "db_name": "databaseabc"
      },
      "HIJ": {
        "db_name": "databasehij"
      },
      "DEF": {
        "db_name": "databasedef"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There's a hash pipe joke here somewhere.

Comment: If you found any of the answers helpful you should select the one you liked best.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you *want* to sort a hash? There's no advantage to it. Instead, get the keys, sort those, then use the keys to retrieve the data in the order you want.

For instance:

```
hash = {'z' => 26, 'a' => 1}
sorted_keys = hash.keys.sort # => ["a", "z"]
hash.values_at(*sorted_keys) # => [1, 26]
```

Using your example hash:

```
hash = {
  "default_attributes": {
    "clients": {
      "ABC": {
        "db_name": "databaseabc"
        },
        "HIJ": {
          "db_name": "databasehij"
          },
          "DEF": {
            "db_name": "databasedef"
          }
        }
      }
    }
clients = hash[:default_attributes][:clients]
sorted_keys = clients.keys.sort # => [:ABC, :DEF, :HIJ]
clients.values_at(*sorted_keys) 
# => [{:db_name=>"databaseabc"},
#     {:db_name=>"databasedef"},
#     {:db_name=>"databasehij"}]
```

Or:

```
sorted_keys.each do |k|
  puts clients[k][:db_name]
end
# >> databaseabc
# >> databasedef
# >> databasehij
```

Note: From looking at your "hash", it really looks like a JSON string missing the original surrounding `{` and `}`. If it is, this question becomes somewhat of an "[XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)". The first question should be "how do I convert a JSON string back to a Ruby object?":

```
require 'json'

hash = '{
  "default_attributes": {
    "clients": {
      "ABC": {
        "db_name": "databaseabc"
        },
        "HIJ": {
          "db_name": "databasehij"
          },
          "DEF": {
            "db_name": "databasedef"
          }
        }
      }
    }'

foo = JSON[hash]
# => {"default_attributes"=>
#      {"clients"=>
#        {"ABC"=>{"db_name"=>"databaseabc"},
#         "HIJ"=>{"db_name"=>"databasehij"},
#         "DEF"=>{"db_name"=>"databasedef"}}}}
```

At that point `foo` would contain a regular hash, and the inconsistent symbol definitions like `"default_attributes":` and `"clients":` would make sense because they ARE JSON hash keys, and the resulting parsed object would be a standard Ruby hash definition. And, you'll have to adjust the code above to access the individual nested hash keys.

Comment: Sorting a hash absolutely makes sense. What if you're doing something like https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/security#validating-requests that requires you to create a HMAC-SHA1 string that's sorted by key?

Comment: That's a very narrow use-case because they're relying on order inside a string. In a running application when you're accessing values based on keys in the hash it makes no sense and adds no advantage when accessing keys.

Comment: Still a use case.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Ruby <1.9, hashes are order-undefined. Sorting them makes no sense.

Ruby 1.9+ has ordered hashes; you would use `sort_by`, then convert your array of hashes back into a hash. Ruby 2.0+ provides `Array#to_h` for this.

```
 data["default_attributes"]["clients"] = data["default_attributes"]["clients"].sort_by(&:first).to_h
```

Comment: Ordered hashes isn't the same as 'sorted'. Ruby maintains the insertion order, but it doesn't sort them.

Comment: You can replace `sort_by(&:first)` with just `sort`. Also I believe you need to change the keys to symbols to work with the OP's hash.

Comment: Yeah, you're right on the sort. The OP provided JSON, though, which will parse to string keys.

Answer (score 0):

```
hash = {
  default_attributes: {
    clients: {
      ABC: {
        "db_name": "databaseabc"
      },
      HIJ: {
        "db_name": "databasehij"
      },
      DEF: {
        "db_name": "databasedef"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you do not wish to mutate `hash`, it's easiest to first make a deep copy:

```
h = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(hash))
```

and then sort the relevant part of `h`:

```
h[:default_attributes][:clients] =
  h[:default_attributes][:clients].sort.to_h
h
  #=> {:default_attributes=>
  #     {:clients=>
  #       {:ABC=>{:db_name=>"databaseabc"},
  #        :DEF=>{:db_name=>"databasedef"},
  #        :HIJ=>{:db_name=>"databasehij"}}}}
```

Confirm `hash` was not mutated:

```
hash
  #=> {:default_attributes=>
  #     {:clients=>
  #       {:ABC=>{:db_name=>"databaseabc"},
  #        :HIJ=>{:db_name=>"databasehij"},
  #        :DEF=>{:db_name=>"databasedef"}}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of our interns came up with a pretty slick gem to perform deep sorts on hashes/arrays:

```
def deep_sort_by(&block)
  Hash[self.map do |key, value|
    [if key.respond_to? :deep_sort_by
      key.deep_sort_by(&block)
    else
      key
    end,

    if value.respond_to? :deep_sort_by
      value.deep_sort_by(&block)
    else
      value
    end]

  end.sort_by(&block)]
end
```

You can inject it into all hashes and then just call it like this:

```
[myMap.deep_sort_by { |obj| obj }][1]
```

The code would be similar for an array. We published "[deepsort](https://rubygems.org/gems/deepsort)" as a gem for others to use. See "[Deeply Sort Nested Ruby Arrays And Hashes](https://www.lucidchart.com/techblog/2016/08/31/deeply-sort-nested-ruby-arrays-and-hashes/)" for additional details.

Disclaimer: I work for this company.